# Queries in Agile process

Tags: agile, agile-project-management, agile-processes

How to determine the story point value in Agile methodology and determine the team velocity? In web search able to get the definition but not the actually process explanation.

Comment: Hi Tom, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is your best bet for this sort of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Story Point](http://scrummethodology.com/scrum-effort-estimation-and-story-points/) is estimated during the Sprint Planning by the team members. It's better if each team member discloses the story point simultanously by using Scrum cards.

For example:

> Product Manager creates a story to add a facebook like button in the company website. Developer A quotes 4 hours. Developer B quotes 5 hours. QA quotes 3 hours. In the end, the team decided to use 4 hours(or 5 hours) development + 3 hours QA as the story point.

[image]

For team Velocity, check this simple [explanation](http://agile101.net/2009/07/10/whats-my-team-velocity/).

Comment: Story points really should never reflect time but relative complexity.